# Hibernate join-table two composite keys that are both foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have two different tables, both of which have composite embedded keys. Both composite keys have in composition the same id `A_ID`.
I want to join table `M` with table `D` in a one to many relationship using a join-table.
The following are some pseudo-java code converted from XML ORM mappings. So please excuse any mistakes written here. The mappings in the final code work so the typos here are not to blame.

```java
@Entity()
public class M {
    @EmbeddedId()
    private EmbeddedMId id;

    @OneToMany(name="d", @JoinTable(name="M-D",
        joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="M_ID", referencedColumnName="M_ID"),
            @JoinColumn(name="A_ID", referencedColumnName="A_ID", table="M")
        },
        inverseJoinColumns={
            @InverseJoinColumn(name="D_ID", referencedColumnName="D_ID"),
            @InverseJoinColumn(name="A_ID", referencedColumnName="A_ID", table="D", insertable="false", updatable="false")
        }
    ))
    private Set<D> dSet;

}
```

```java
@Embeddable()
public class EmbeddedMId {
    @Basic() private String A_ID;
    @Basic() private String M_ID;
}
```

```java
@Embeddable()
public class EmbeddedDId {
    @Basic() private String A_ID;
    @Basic() private String D_ID;
}
```

As you can see, the embeddables both use `A_ID` therefore we tried to make the 2nd A_ID in the join-table be readonly. The application starts and the mappings seem to be okay.

The problem is whenever I want to insert a new `D` object in the `M` entity, hibernate throws an SQL error `invalid column index` because while the prepared statement is correct as seen bellow, hibernate only provides the first 2 parameters instead of all three. (Values provided by hibernate are `(VALID_M_ID, VALID_A_ID)` instead of providing 3 values)

```sql
INSERT INTO M_D("M_ID", "A_ID", "D_ID") VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

If I rename the 2nd inverseJoinColumn to have a new column name and make it insertable/updatable, the problem is solved. But this means that the `A_ID` is duplicated in both `A_ID` and `A_REPEAT_ID` column and this is what I want to avoid.

```java
@InverseJoinColumn(name="A_REPEAT_ID", referencedColumnName="A_ID", table="D")
```

Is there a way to tell Hibernate that my `EmbeddedDId` needs to be mapped over the `D_ID` and `A_ID` (readonly) correctly when doing the insertions?
I hope my explanation is clear enough, but feel free to ask for any clarifications.
Hibernate version is `5.2.17-FINAL`

**EDIT**

The only other entity that is important in this case is pretty simple. But as requested I'll write it here

```java
@Entity()
public class D {
    @EmbeddedId()
    private EmbeddedDId id;

    /* other basic fields here */
}
```

Comment: I would suggest on using `IdClass` to do this, as `EmbeddedId` is a pain in the ass to work with when having foreign keys. Aside from that though, can you please share all your entities in order to have a clearer view on what you are trying to do?

Comment: @akortex91 I added the last Entity that is needed for the process (which hasn't been previously added because of its simplicity). Also we're not using IdClass because it's not possible with our infrastructure. We depend on a common kernel that allows only one ID (annotation is done in super class). The solution was using embeddables therefore the above code

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `insertable = false, updatable = false` does what you want here. If you want the target column `A_ID` on `D` to be readonly, then you will have to map the column in the target entity `D` and specify there that the column is `insertable = false, updatable = false` but not on this association.

Comment: Unfortunately you misunderstood. The field that is readonly is in the Join Table, not in the D entity. I want my Join Table to have 3 columns instead of 4 (2 of which would be identical because of how composite IDs were created)

Comment: I see what you mean. Unfortunately that is not possible with a `@JoinTable`. I think you will have to map the join table as entity in this case and have a three column embedded id on that entity. In there, you can still map two `@ManyToOne` associations and map the inverse side with `@OneToMany(mappedBy="...")`, but this kind of `@ManyToMany` association you are looking for can't be modeled with JPA AFAIK.

Comment: by not using Hibernate, it is normally possible and easy to implement. That is why I was assuming there should be a way to do this with JPA/Hibernate too, therefore I posted this question. :) 
In the end I went with 4 columns as it was time-sensitive. But I still feel there is a way to make it work :)

Comment: Like I wrote, it is possible, but you must map the join table as entity.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Unfortunately that is not an option as we're using the DDD paradigm and only Aggregate Roots can modify entities. Everything else needs to be element collection or join tables. It's complicated :)
I honestly thought Hibernate would have such a mechanism to take care of this by itself through configurations

Comment: Oh wow, what an architect you have.. I'm sorry for you. Maybe tell him that you can still follow DDD principles while mapping the join table as entity. You just don't expose this detail to the outside world directly. Yeah, Hibernate can do it, but only by mapping it as entity.

Comment: Yeah well if it's an entity it's presumed that it can be modified any time and that is not allowed. It is what it is.... Thank you for your help!! :)